# Android app which uses google maps api not working

Tags: android

Here is the my layout file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="40.7484"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-73.9857"
    map:cameraTilt="65"
    map:cameraZoom="17"
    />
```

I have put all the required API Key the correct permission and meta data and Opengl features in android manifest files but there are no result only a blank screen with google on bottom left

Comment: It's not error actually but nothing  in displayed on the fragment . This is my very first time using google maps so i don't know if its an error or something else .. Sorry to be so vague

Comment: Did you follow steps? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#o_arquivo_de_layout_xml

Comment: Can you show your code for the activity/fragment you're trying to display the map in?

Comment: yes. i did it shows blank..

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: A blank map is always a case of something wrong with the API key.  You can get a map to display without any code.  Check the logs for an error related to your API key.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#etapa_4_obter_uma_chave_da_google_maps_api)